# MySQL Server on Mac (Mojave) suddenly stopped and won't restart

Tags: mysql, macos-mojave

In System Preferences, MySql connection status just keeps toggling between green and red. When trying to start in Terminal, I get:

> garofanwnstairs:~ mgarofano$ mysqld
>
> 2020-06-10T23:32:06.839640Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.16-macos10.14-x86_64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 1353
>
> 2020-06-10T23:32:06.843055Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-8.0.16-macos10.14-x86_64/data/garofanwnstairs.lower-test
>
> 2020-06-10T23:32:06.843066Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-8.0.16-macos10.14-x86_64/data/ is case insensitive
>
> 2020-06-10T23:32:06.843150Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/usr/local/mysql-8.0.16-macos10.14-x86_64/data/' (OS errno: 13 - Permission denied)
>
> 2020-06-10T23:32:06.843217Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
>
> 2020-06-10T23:32:06.862668Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.16-macos10.14-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Help! Thanks!

Comment: You don't see the **Permission denied** in the text?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by entering the following:

```
sudo chown -RL root:mysql /usr/local/mysql
sudo chown -RL mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Now, can someone tell me how the permissions got messed up in the first place? I made no changes. ??